# Sitecore Commerce 9.2 - sxa.storefront.com - Illegal recursion detected: GetModel

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I did install the Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.2 locally, without any issues. After installation, I did clean up the databases, rebuilt link databases, rebuilt the indexes and republished the site. 
I can log in to Sitecore Client, access Business Tools and view the default home page. 
However, when I navigate to "https://sxa.storefront.com/" I'm getting an error. 
"Illegal recursion detected: GetModel"
Note: Previously, I did install Sitecore Commerce 9.2 and did not get this issue.

Below is an image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was strange, previously I did setup several times Sitecore Commerce Engine 9.2 locally and I did not get this issue. After, cleaning up the previous versions and reinstalling a new Sitecore Commerce Engine 9.2 I did get this issue.

However, it was a known issue that Sitecore provided a patch. 
Download the package, unzip, copy config file and dll to your project. Restart Sitecore and sxa storefront. It should work.

Patch:
[Sitecore.Support.247244](https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.247244/releases)